# WPF custom ContentPresenter does not bind properties

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, contentpresenter

I have a custom class derived from `ContentPresenter` which has a DepenedencyProperty. However, when I attempt to bind it, nothing happens (Source's getter is not called, content is not updated, no errors are logged in Trace):

```
public class IsReadOnlyCellPresenter : ContentPresenter
{
    [Bindable(true)]
    public string Text
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string), typeof(IsReadOnlyCellPresenter), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null));
}
```

xaml:

```
<local:IsReadOnlyCellPresenter Text="{Binding Path=MyProperty, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
    <local:IsReadOnlyCellPresenter.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </local:IsReadOnlyCellPresenter.ContentTemplate>
</local:IsReadOnlyCellPresenter>
```

If I use static value (e.g. `Text="Foo"`) it works as expected. If I derive from ContentControl  (`class IsReadOnlyCellPresenter : ContentControl`), the `Text` binding works but not `Mode=TemplatedParent` which points to nowhere.
What is the issue with ContentPresenter here? Can `ContentPresenter` be derived from?

Comment: What is all this supposed to do, when you could just write `<Label Content="{Binding MyProperty}"/>`? Note that setting `Mode=TwoWay` and `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` is pointless anyway.

Comment: That said, `RelativeSource TemplatedParent` is meant to be used in a ControlTemplate, not a DataTemplate.

Comment: @Clemens Reusability. I need 30-40 of those controls, each of them bind to different property but bunch of same logic/events/etc.. The solution looks promising, already got it working with ContentControl, but the bindings get bizzare. Good tip with the ControlTemplate, checking visual tree shows there are actually two nested preseners thats why it does not reach the correct target. I will try the ControlTemplate.

Comment: That's weird. Why don't you bind the TextBox directly to MyProperty? You should set the Content property to the data source of the DataTemplate. The extra property on the extended presenter is not necessary. The ContentTemplate is designed to be applied automatically to the Content.

Comment: I think your relative source binding should find the ancestor of type contentpresenter.

Comment: I can't find an official source, but I've found what [this blog](https://alexfeinberg.wordpress.com/2014/10/11/wpf-the-real-difference-between-contentcontrol-and-contentpresenter/) says to be correct: "ContentPresenter’s DataContext is automatically set to the value of its Content property, while ContentControl’s DataContext is not." This explains why bindings don't really work with `ContentPresenter`, the source is always wrong.